# Why does Bing (and Bing Custom Search) return no results for certain Wikipedia pages?

Tags: wikipedia, bing, bing-api, bing-custom-search

I am trying to use Bing Custom Search over certain Wikipedia pages.  However, I am finding that there are many pages that don't return any results in Bing Custom Search (or on Bing Search).

For example, you can search Bing for `site:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington name` and get a response back for that one web page.  However, if you choose from any of the following dog breed names (really almost any dog breed from this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dog_breeds):

```
https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_Fox_Terrier
https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Kishu
https://wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Cocker_Spaniel
```

as the site, searching `site:{site_from_list_above} dog` (for example `site:https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_Fox_Terrier dog`) there are no results.  Am I searching wrong, or does Bing just not cache these pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: after talking with Bing Support and playing with the URLs myself, I found that there were two issues:

1. The urls need to not be redirects, as `https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Kishu` takes you to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kishu`.
2. The urls that have special characters in them (such as `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chihuahua_(dog)` need to be replaced (this means “(“ with “%28” and “)” with “%29”, etc.).  More details on escaping can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Hope this helps someone else!